# Boost geometry register Point 2d as shared pointer

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, boost-geometry

i would like to register a custom 2d Point with

```
class CustomPoint{
public:
double X;
double Y;
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(CustomPoint, double, cs::cartesian, CustomPoint::X, CustomPoint::Y)
```

this works well and i can register a ring

but when I use a shared pointer:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<CustomPoint> cpPtr;
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(cpPtr, double, cs::cartesian, ?, ?)
```

i have no idea how i can acess my X and Y with this macro. Is that possible?
The definition of the boost macro is

> Field0 Member containing first (usually x) coordinate
>
> Field1 Member containing second (usually y) coordinate

Can i point to the field witch contain my X coorinate with the shared pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own traits:

```
using cpPtr = boost::shared_ptr<CustomPoint>;

namespace boost { namespace geometry { namespace traits {
    BOOST_GEOMETRY_DETAIL_SPECIALIZE_POINT_TRAITS(cpPtr, 2, double, cs::cartesian)

    template<> struct access<cpPtr, 0> {
        static inline double get(cpPtr const& p) { return p->X; }
        static inline void set(cpPtr& p, double const& value) { p->X = value; }
    };
    template<> struct access<cpPtr, 1> {
        static inline double get(cpPtr const& p) { return p->Y; }
        static inline void set(cpPtr& p, double const& value) { p->Y = value; }
    };
}}}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2959ae3866b9075)**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

using namespace boost::geometry;

class CustomPoint{
public:
    double X;
    double Y;
};

using cpPtr = boost::shared_ptr<CustomPoint>;

namespace boost { namespace geometry { namespace traits {
    BOOST_GEOMETRY_DETAIL_SPECIALIZE_POINT_TRAITS(cpPtr, 2, double, cs::cartesian)

    template<> struct access<cpPtr, 0> {
        static inline double get(cpPtr const& p) { return p->X; }
        static inline void set(cpPtr& p, double const& value) { p->X = value; }
    };
    template<> struct access<cpPtr, 1> {
        static inline double get(cpPtr const& p) { return p->Y; }
        static inline void set(cpPtr& p, double const& value) { p->Y = value; }
    };
}}}

int main()
{
    auto p1 = boost::make_shared<CustomPoint>();
    auto p2 = boost::make_shared<CustomPoint>();

    namespace bg = boost::geometry;

    bg::assign_values(p1, 1, 1);
    bg::assign_values(p2, 2, 2);

    double d = bg::distance(p1, p2);

    std::cout << "Distance: " << d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
Distance: 1.41421
```

Comment: Hello i have on question to that. If i use union clipping with a polygons of my customPoints, boost has to dynamically allocates memory with new for every Vertex. How i can define that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Hunk I don't think you can. share_ptr is about _sharing_ ownership, not about cloning. For that you'd need a `value_ptr<>` with cloning policy. Several are floating on the web. But really, think twice and just use value-types as point types...

Comment: hello thank you for your answer. The problem is that i need the sharing ownership in some other steps. I tried to use the UNIONClipping(myPointerType,myPointerType,std::vector<BoostPolygon>), are different geometry types on union clipping not possible?

Comment: @Hunk I have a working sample of a point type that is effectively a `shared_ptr` with auto-allocation behaviour. If you post a separate question, I'll post it as an answer. _(That said, I cannot see when this would be useful. I will elaborate on this too if you post your question)_

Comment: thank you for your time and help. i posted a new question for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100112/boost-union-with-auto-allocation