# Boost geometry union with auto-allocation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

using namespace boost::geometry;

class CustomPoint{
public:
    double X;
    double Y;
};

using cpPtr = boost::shared_ptr<CustomPoint>;

namespace boost { namespace geometry { namespace traits {
    BOOST_GEOMETRY_DETAIL_SPECIALIZE_POINT_TRAITS(cpPtr, 2, double, cs::cartesian)

    template<> struct access<cpPtr, 0> {
        static inline double get(cpPtr const& p) { return p->X; }
        static inline void set(cpPtr& p, double const& value) { p->X = value; }
    };
    template<> struct access<cpPtr, 1> {
        static inline double get(cpPtr const& p) { return p->Y; }
        static inline void set(cpPtr& p, double const& value) { p->Y = value; }
    };
}}}

int main()
{
  std::vector<cpPtr> one,Two;
  //init polys
  std::vector< std::vector<cpPtr> > output;
  boost::geometry::union_(one,two,output)

}
```

Hello i tried a boost::shared_ptr as polygon. The problem is when i do union clipping the algorithm didn't allocate memory. Anyone knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

First let me take the time to say I'm puzzled by the motivation for this "awkward" point type choice.

It seems to me that

- if you have very few points, then the sharing would not appear to be essential
- if you *do* then it would appear that the overhead of shared_ptr (2x pointer overhead and atomic reference count locking) would prevent scaling.

For the best of both worlds (points that can be in multiple collections at once) have you considered straight pointers, or perhaps even Boost Intrusive containers (which will not take ownership over contained elements)?

All question aside, here's one way to do it:

---

You can do a simplistic wrapper around a shared_ptr that allows you to use it in this way:

```
template<typename T>
    struct shared_instancing : boost::shared_ptr<T> {
        using boost::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr;

        shared_instancing(boost::shared_ptr<T> sp = boost::make_shared<T>()) 
            : boost::shared_ptr<T>(sp)
        { }
    };
```

As you can see, it will default construct to a new instance; See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f204dcd0b7129f9)**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace boost::geometry;

struct CustomPoint{
    double X;
    double Y;
};

namespace {
    template<typename T>
        struct shared_instancing : boost::shared_ptr<T> {
            using boost::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr;

            shared_instancing(boost::shared_ptr<T> sp = boost::make_shared<T>()) 
                : boost::shared_ptr<T>(sp)
            { }
        };
}

using cpPtr = shared_instancing<CustomPoint>; // boost::shared_ptr<CustomPoint>;

namespace boost { namespace geometry { namespace traits {
    BOOST_GEOMETRY_DETAIL_SPECIALIZE_POINT_TRAITS(cpPtr, 2, double, cs::cartesian)

    template<> struct access<cpPtr, 0> {
        static inline double get(cpPtr const& p) { return p->X; }
        static inline void set(cpPtr& p, double const& value) { p->X = value; }
    };
    template<> struct access<cpPtr, 1> {
        static inline double get(cpPtr const& p) { return p->Y; }
        static inline void set(cpPtr& p, double const& value) { p->Y = value; }
    };
}}}

int main()
{
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<cpPtr > polygon;

    polygon green, blue;

    boost::geometry::read_wkt(
        "POLYGON((2 1.3,2.4 1.7,2.8 1.8,3.4 1.2,3.7 1.6,3.4 2,4.1 3,5.3 2.6,5.4 1.2,4.9 0.8,2.9 0.7,2 1.3)"
            "(4.0 2.0, 4.2 1.4, 4.8 1.9, 4.4 2.2, 4.0 2.0))", green);

    boost::geometry::read_wkt(
        "POLYGON((4.0 -0.5 , 3.5 1.0 , 2.0 1.5 , 3.5 2.0 , 4.0 3.5 , 4.5 2.0 , 6.0 1.5 , 4.5 1.0 , 4.0 -0.5))", blue);

    std::vector<polygon> output;
    boost::geometry::union_(green, blue, output);

    int i = 0;
    std::cout << "green || blue:" << std::endl;
    for(polygon const& p: output)
    {
        std::cout << i++ << ": " << boost::geometry::area(p) << std::endl;
    }
}
```